# Object variable or With block variable not set - Run-time error '91'

Tags: excel, vba

I have some simple copy and paste VBA code in Excel that was previously working. There may have been a update of some sort because now I keep getting the error in the title. The code is below:

**y.Sheets("Data").Range("A1").PasteSpecial**

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim x As Workbook
Dim y As Workbook

Set x = 
Workbooks.Open("https://nameofComp.sharepoint.com/sites/TechnicalBusiness/SharePoint%20- 
%20Technical%20Business/Business%20Architects/Timesheet/Timesheet.xlsm")
Set y = 
Workbooks.Open("https://nameofComp.sharepoint.com/sites/TechnicalBusiness/SharePoint%20- 
%20Technical%20Business/Technical%20Coordaintor/Timesheet%20Anaysis/TimehsheetAnalysis.xlsm")
x.Sheets("Form1").Range("A2:U1000").Copy
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
y.Sheets("Data").Range("A1").PasteSpecial
x.Close

End Sub
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Do you have read-write access to files without using vba?

Comment: @BigBen I have added it to the question - Sorry

Comment: Are either of the workbooks already open?

Comment: After update I'd suppose that you don't have a `Sheets("Data")` in the target wb

Comment: @BigBen yes I workbook y is open

Comment: I may have to find a similar question, but I believe if the workbook is already open then `Workbooks.Open` can cause issues.

Comment: @BigBen Is there a way to change the code so y is the active workbook - would that help perhaps?

Comment: `Set y = ActiveWorkbook` - but if you go that route I'd move that line before `Set x = ...`. What workbook is this code in? Is it actually in workbook y?

Comment: @BigBen Will give it a go. Yes the code is in the y workbook

Comment: Then use `ThisWorkbook`

Comment: @BigBen That worked! Seems excel gets funny when trying to open an active workbook

Comment: @BigBen Sorry I am new to this, is there anywhere where I could rate your answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Workbooks.Open` can cause issues if the workbook is already open.

Since the code is in workbook `y`, use `ThisWorkbook`:

```
Set y = ThisWorkbook
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim x As Workbook
Dim y As Workbook

Set x = 
Workbooks.Open("https://nameofComp.sharepoint.com/sites/TechnicalBusiness/SharePoint%20- 
%20Technical%20Business/Business%20Architects/Timesheet/Timesheet.xlsm")
Set y = 
Workbooks.Open("https://nameofComp.sharepoint.com/sites/TechnicalBusiness/SharePoint%20- 
%20Technical%20Business/Technical%20Coordaintor/Timesheet%20Anaysis/TimehsheetAnalysis.xlsm")
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
x.worksheets("Form1").Range("A2:U1000").Copy
y.worksheets("Data").Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll
x.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: `Paste` is an optional argument so I would be surprised if this fixes the issue.

Comment: No sorry this didn't fix the issue - the same line still has the issue